# Iterator implementation on custom struct - problems

Tags: rust, serialization, iterator, deserialization

Im trying print out a encoded hex string of some basic data ive inserted as a lesson how to serialize/deserialize data. However todo this im having to implement an iterator for a Struct that has a single element of type Vec. Im getting the below error and don't understand why, I realize my code is incomplete in the next() implementation. I'm fairly new to iterators, any help would be appreciated.

Error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `iter_mut` found for struct `MyData` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:110:22
    |
21  | pub(crate) struct MyData {
    | ------------------------ method `iter_mut` not found for this struct
...
110 |     for v in my_data.iter_mut() {
    |
```

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(transparent)]
struct MyHex {
    #[serde(with = "hex::serde")]
    hex: Vec<u8>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub(crate) struct MyData {
    data: Vec<MyHex>,
}

impl Iterator for MyData {

    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>;

}


fn main() -> Result<()> {

    let data = "
        { 
            \"data\": [\"bbac4013c1ca3482155b584d35dac185\",
                \"a08898e81f1ddb6612aa12641b856aa9\",
                \"bbac4013c1ca3482155b584d35dac185\"
            ]
        }";

    let my_data: MyData = serde_json::from_str(data)?;


    for v in my_data.iter_mut() {
        println!("{:?}", hex::encode(v));
    }


    return Ok(());
}
```

Comment: As the compiler says, `iter_mut` is not a method of your struct `MyData`. You either need to implement it and forward it to `data` **or** use `for v in my_data` because that's what the `Iterator` trait is about.

Comment: HI, could you please elaborate a little on the `Iterator` trait? 
From what i can tell, the Iterator needs to implement at least the `next()` function.

At the moment im not returning back the `Some`/`None` from the `Option` return. How do i figure out what the next 'Item' is in the Vector within the `next()` function?

Comment: Your question in your post is now a different one than in this comment. I have the feeling that you don't have much experience with rust, so please take your time and learn the language by reading [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/) and using [rust by example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/). It will probably help you and resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You question is a little fuzzy but let's try to see what we can do:

### Iterating over inner field

If you want to do something with the data byte by byte, you can iterate over data itself:

```rust
for hex in my_data.data { ... }
```

### Iterating without exposing inner fields

You can also return iterator over `data` without exposing the field to the rest of the code:

```rust
impl MyData {
  fn iter_data(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &MyHex> {
    self.data.iter()
  }
}

...
for hex in my_data.iter_data() { ... }
```

### Implementing `IntoIterator`

If you want `MyData` work as an iterator, you can implement `IntoIterator` trait for it:

```rust
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a MyData {
    type Item = &'a MyHex;
    type IntoIter = std::slice::Iter<'a, MyHex>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.data.iter()
    }
}

...

for v in &my_data {
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7ef702837ffd5878db0fbd3b5776f573)

### Implementing `Iterator` for `MyData`

To implement `Iterator` you need to provide the `next` method, which on every call will return the next item in the iterator while there are any items left. To do so you would add a field to you `MyData` that keeps track of the last item that was return, and increment that pointer on every call of `next()`.

But from your code I guess this is not something you actually want. Go rather with one of the previous options.